# Nested composite component broken in JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: jsf-2, jboss7.x, composite-component

We use composite components inside other components in our project. Everything works just fine on JBoss **7.1.0**, but on JBoss **7.1.1** we get errors like this:

```
No handlers found for exception javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: 
/resources/components/my/bigComponent.xhtml @21,47 <my:nestedComponent> 
Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/my, 
but no tag was defined for name: nestedComponent
```

We tried the solution suggested in [this JBoss community thread](https://community.jboss.org/message/723634?tstart=0), but it changed nothing to our problem (seams we're not [the only one in this case](https://community.jboss.org/message/724242?tstart=0), and the solution may not work because we're also in a `ui:define` tag from a template file).

Here our two components:

The nesting:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ...>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
  xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/my" >

<cc:interface componentType="...">
    <h:panelGroup>
        <cc:attribute name="someAttribute" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
     <my:nestedComponent content="a text" />
</cc:implementation>
</html>
```

The nested:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ...>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="content" />
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.content}" />
</cc:implementation>

</html>
```

Is it a regression? Are we doing something wrong ? In the 1st link, the suggested solution implies in the nesting component something like this:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:facet name="greet1"/>
    <composite:facet name="greet2"/>
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <lib:greet1 name="Stan" />
    <lib:greet2 name="Silvert" />
</composite:implementation>
```

What are this `composite:facet` without any `composite:renderFacet` for?

Comment: Which JSF implementation are you using? Note since MyFaces 2.1.6/2.0.12 composite component cannot contains library names with slashes. Your library name is 'components/my', which is invalid. See [MYFACES-3454](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3454) for details.

Comment: We're using Primefaces 3.2 and the Mojarra version provided by JBoss 7.1.1. We always used this kind of library names without any problem until the last JBoss version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Valentinx in [this thread](https://community.jboss.org/message/724991) found a workaround.

The idea is to put the faulty namespace declarations on the `<composite:implementation>` itself, so

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ...>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
  xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/my" >
<cc:interface />
<cc:implementation>
     <my:nestedComponent content="a text" />
</cc:implementation>
</html>
```

becomes

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ...>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite" >
<cc:interface />
<cc:implementation xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/my">
     <my:nestedComponent content="a text" />
</cc:implementation>
</html>
```

(notice the **`<cc:implementation xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/my">`** tag)

This works like a charm!

Comment: Wow, irritating, but thanks for the information--a massive help, I would have lost a couple days.

Comment: me too, man... why can't Redhat stick with the JSF 2. spec when they upgrade their JBoss server ?

Comment: ARRRRGHGH! +1 --thanks for the complete information. (disturbingly I've already up-voted this information)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Xavier for the answer: that is right on!  I wanted to add comment, but don't have rep. to do that.

In my case, the problem is a little difference, with error on template (not in composite:implementation), and I found a solution that does not include <cc:implementation> ...

Instead, moved xmlns:layoutComp in template from <html> to a container (both 'div' and 'span' worked):

```
<span xmlns:layoutComp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/layoutComp">
        <layoutComp:navigation />
</span>
```